# Pesquisa ao banco SQL em um texto salvo pelo TinyMCE

Tags: c#, html, .net, entity-framework, linq

Estou utilizando o TinyMCE para edição de textos no meu site. Quando pesquiso uma palavra com acento. Ex.: `análise`, a consulta não acha porque no banco está salvo em HTML `an&aacutelise`. Estou utilizando ASP.Net MVC com SQL Server.

Comment: E onde está seu código e os dados relevantes para ajudarmos você? Já adianto que ou você deverá mudar a forma de salvar os dados ou terá que alterar os termos pesquisados para refletir a forma como é salvo.

Comment: Desculpe, segue o código.                                                        listaNoticia = context.GBV_Noticia.Where(x => x.idPessoa == idPessoa && x.dsConteudo.Contains(texto) && x.icAtivo == "S" && x.dtExclusao == null && x.dtPublicacao <= DateTime.Now && (x.dtForaDoAr == null || x.dtForaDoAr >= DateTime.Now)).OrderBy(x =>x.dtPublicacao).ToList();

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 2):

Não tem muita informação mas basicamente o que você precisa fazer é tratar o HTML como uma forma especial. Deve decidir se converte o HTML para um texto comum antes de gravá-lo no banco de dados ou converter o seu termo de busca para a codificação de HTML. Você precisa decidir se deseja gravar como HTML mesmo ou se a gravação está em formado inadequado para você e precisa deixá-lo em texto normal.

Dependendo do que precisa isto não resolverá tudo mas isto é o básico que deve fazer.

Métodos utilitários para fazer isto: [`WebUtility.HtmlEncode()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webutility.htmlencode?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-6.0#System_Net_WebUtility_HtmlEncode_System_String_) e [`WebUtility.HtmlDecode()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webutility.htmldecode?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-6.0#System_Net_WebUtility_HtmlDecode_System_String_).

Seguindo seu código, deve ser algo assim:

```
listaNoticia = context.GBV_Noticia.Where(x => x.idPessoa == idPessoa &&
    x.dsConteudo.Contains(WebUtility.HtmlEncode(texto)) && x.icAtivo == "S" &&
    x.dtExclusao == null && x.dtPublicacao <= DateTime.Now &&
    (x.dtForaDoAr == null || x.dtForaDoAr >= DateTime.Now))
    .OrderBy(x =>x.dtPublicacao).ToList();
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Linq/Html.cs).

Comment: Não testei o seu código, mas me parece que funcionaria também. Resolvi de outra forma, acrescentei mais um parâmetro no código script do TinyMCE.   _entity_encoding: "raw"_  Funcionou.